# JQuery synchronous animate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery synchronous animation with window.setInterval

```
window.setInterval(function(){        
    $("#pageflip img").stop().animate({width:'+=2px',height:'+=2px'}, 800,null,function(){
        $("#pageflip img").stop().animate({width:'-=2px',height:'-=2px'}, 800);
    });        
},1600)
```

What happening here when I loose focus from page window (switch tab or open another application, not viewing animation page)  callback function is not called, image width and height always increasing (not back to its normal position) as long as I remain in same page window it is working fine. I am newbie in jquery any help please?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Remove the null before your callback.

Answer (score 1):

`.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )`.
You have the easing parameter value set to null, it should be left empty or set to linear (more options when using the easing plugin).

> **Easing :**
>   The remaining parameter of .animate() is a string naming an easing function to use. An easing function specifies the speed at which the animation progresses at different points within the animation. The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the jQuery UI suite.

Remove the ,null or replace it with Linear/swing, before your callback. By default the easing is set to swing.

Refer to the [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more details.